# How to loop through and find a specific word in multiple text files?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, search, count

So I have compiled a bunch of txt files and I got python to combine them and print all of them in the console as seen here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import glob
import sys 
rally_files= glob.glob("C:/Users/epicr/Downloads/archive/*.txt")
for file in rally_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        lines= f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            for word in line.split('\n'):
                print (word)
```

The output works here it is right here:

```
word word word word word word word word word word more random words Joe Joe random random Joe
```

Now, I want to loop through each single word in the huge text file  I just made and find a specific word. If that word exists, I want to add it in a counter. Lets say if if it detects the word 'Joe', the counter will go up. Here is my code below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import glob
import sys 
rally_files= glob.glob("C:/Users/epicr/Downloads/archive/*.txt")
count=0
for file in rally_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        lines= f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            for word in line.split('\n'):
                if word in line.split('\n')== 'Joe':
                        count +=1
print (count)
```

It seems to not be picking up anything. I know for a fact the word 'Joe' has shown up about 300ish times.. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count=0
for file in rally_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        lines= f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            count += line.count("Joe")
```

Comment: Mind you explaining your answer please, and how this solved the issue? Cheers!